# Failed to find byte code for javax/sql/XAConnection

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, connection, jtds

I am trying to connect SQL Server with android using

**jtds-1.3.1.rar**

here is my connection code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection);
    String url = "jdbc:jtdc:sqlserver://192.168.1.4/DATABASE";
    try {
        TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conn);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        textViewToChange.setText("Connected");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

but when i  try to run the project, android studio's message box display this error

> Failed to find byte code for javax/sql/XAConnection

[image]
What is that mean ?? why i get this error ???

Thank for Help....!!!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue with 
"IOException: Failed to find byte code ..." after updating AndroidStudio.

It looks like AndroidStudio [knows that](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718) they have this issue, but haven't done any hotfix as of now. One solution is to go to AndroidStudio settings and disable "Instant Run" completely (even if you were not using instant run).

*In my case, the class that was not found was referred to by one library that I was using and that class really was missing from the project (they did have try and cache around this code). Disabling "Instant Run" helped me fix the issue.*

Answer (score 2):

Disable Instant run and run the program.

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem also, but I remove the "Gradle-aware Make" from the Run/Debug configurations -> Before Launch and do the rebuild manualy did solve the problem for me

This is more a work arround I would say since now I have to do this manually the build every time, but at least I wont get that error any more

Forgot to say that this only started to happen on a project that I use that Lib after updating the Android Studio to 3.1